# I wanna to delete all files and directories in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command

I have to delete all directories and files which should be 3 years back from current date what should be the specific command for that in linux.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you define "3 years back": created, last modified... If that's last modified, you can do something like this to **list** those files

```
find /directory -mtime +1095
```

/directory is the starting directory, +1095 meaning modified 1095 days ago, 365*3.

If you're okay with the list, then add the delete option

```
find /directory -mtime +1095 -delete
```

Be careful not to put -delete before -mtime, there's a specific order there. See `man find` for more informations.